# How to delete PHP session by clicking a HTML button?

Tags: php, session, event-handling, web-development-server

I want to delete all sessions of my webpage using PHP when the user clicks on a specific button... Below is the related code:

```
<a href="#" class="log" name="log">delete sessions</a>                        
<?php                                                                         
//when button is clicked then run command: session_destroy()                                                                           
?>
```

If it isn't possible then is there a way I can destroy PHP sessions using javascript action listeners?

Comment: Are you trying to destroy cookies or the session. please make this more obvious

Comment: Sorry it is sessions,I mixed them up X(

Comment: you need to make a request to the server (php), either post or get, from you client (browser) to clear out all the sessions

Comment: @keaton can you write code?

Comment: Read up on how to use AJAX to make requests to server with javascript. Or instead of an `<a>` tag make a simple form that when submitted deletes the session

Comment: Hi @ShahEryarAhmed , could U mark answer as accepted if resolve the problem? If not will try help with issue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### *Hi*

One of ways to achive it is simple form and destroy session when the specified variable (a flag) was sent via for example POST.

The HTML form with hidden input and button:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="destroySession" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="DESTROY SESSION" />
</form>
```

PHP code for catch the flag from form:

```
$destroySessionFlag = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'destroySession');
if ($destroySessionFlag == 1) {
    session_destroy();
}
```

#### *Cheers*